# how to display vlaue comparing with 2 different rows

Tags: mysql

I have database name exams.

There are 3 tables : 
1 is students 
2 is group
3 is pass_group

In students, there are 3 columns

```
name, name_id, class_id
```

In group, there are 4 columns :

```
class_id, group_name, name_id, name
```

In pass_group, there are 2 columns :

```
pass_id class_id
```

Now i want to display only name of all pass_id.

How to do it.. ? I tried :

```
SELECT `name_id` FROM `guild` WHERE `group`.`class_id` = `pass_group`.`pass_id`;
```

But error :-(

Can you help me solve this ? I am at very very beginner stage

Answer (score 0):

Use left join. For example 
`select a.name, b.pass_id from students as a left join pass_group as b on b.class_id = a.class_id`

[SQL JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)